# Can I execute a command and have it show up in the command log (time travel) after a timeout error has been thrown by a command or assertion?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, cypress

I have been testing a chat application with Cypress. The application has internal state that is only accessible to me upon ending the session. I want to be able to ensure that internal state is reported after every test run for debugging purposes. Currently, this works without a problem on passing tests. The last command I issue in all tests is clicking the end session and that is then saved in Cypress. The issue I'm facing is that once Cypress fails on a command or assertion, I can not tell the application to dump the state and have it saved in the command log.

I was able to get the finalize() function to run after the error was thrown using the below code and the result was displayed in the browser, but the result was not in the command log/time travel after all the tests in the spec completed.

```
Cypress.on('fail', (error, runnable) => {
    Cypress.$('#finalizeButton').click()
    throw error
})
```

Comment: Can you try Cypress logging `cy.log(message)` . Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/log.html#Syntax

Comment: I don't have access to cy from the support/index.js file that I could tell. Also, the state output is long and so would be unusable in the tiny command log. But thank you!